# Python easiest way to change background on Mac

Tags: python

I want to change the background of my MacBook with a python script, but I want to know how I can change the background of my Mac the easiest way. I have tried subprocess, but I get this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'`

Is there another way of changing the background?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new with python.

This is what I have tried with subprocess as an example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('ls')
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431205/how-can-i-programmatically-change-the-background-in-mac-os-x **or** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512281/set-macos-wallpaper-folder-via-command-line

Comment: The problem is that the subprocess is not working. I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: `subprocess.run(...)` was introduced in Python 3.5. So you are probably running the script with Python2 ?

Comment: How can I run the script with python 3.5 or newer?

Comment: Try `python3 myScript.py`.

Comment: I have tried python3 when I run it, but got this error: AttributeError: partially initialized module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'run' (most likely due to a circular import)